# What does area under t distribution give?

Tags: probability, statistics

My question is really simple but i have not been able to find any satisfactory answer anywhere, hence asking here. What does area under t distribution mean?
Example : for normal distribution, P(z< a) will be given by F(a), the area under curve from -infinity to a. But if i want to find P(t< a) where t is t distributed, how do i find it? What does t table value give?

Comment: If the random variable is t-distributed then the table of the cdf gives you $P(T<a)$. The number of degrees of freedom is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one standard normal distribution, so a full page of print is often used to show the distribution in detail.
By contrast, there are many different t distributions, one for each number of degrees of freedom (DF). In a typical printed table of t distributions, there is one row for each DF.
The highly selected information about the distribution is provided in that one row.

**Using a t table.** In a typical normal table, probabilities are given in the *body* of the table and $z$-values are given in the margins. In a typical t table, probabilities are given along the top margin and t values are given along each row of the body of the table.

***Connections to normal table.*** For orientation, you might begin by looking at the very last row of your "t table." It may be marked `Inf` or with an $\infty$-symbol. Values in that one row are for the normal distribution. Along that row you may find `1.96`in the column marked `0.025`. That means for standard normal $Z$ you have $P(Z > 1.96) - 0.025.$

- Now see if you can find that same information in your printed normal table: From the margins of the table, find `1.96`, the in the body
  of the table you may find a probability for $P(Z \le 1.96)= 0.9750$ or $P(0 < Z < 1.96)$ $= 0.9750 - 0.5000$ $= 0.4750,$ depending on the style of your normal table.
- Try to match several numbers on the bottom row of the t table with corresponding values in the normal table. (You may have
  to do some rounding to get approximate values.)

Back to the t table: Look at the row for DF = 20 and the column marked `.05`. You should find `1.725` which means
$P(T > 1.725) = 0.05.$

Notes: (1) You usually can't find exact P-values from
a printed normal table. Exact P-values are usually obtained from computer printouts of statistical tests.

***Approximate P-values for t table.*** If DF = 20, and the t statistic is $1.762$ you can
look along row 20 of your t table to find that
$1.725 < 1.762 <2.086.$ The column headers corresponding
to $1.725$ and $2.086$ are $.05$ and $.025,$ respectively.
So you know that the P-value corresponding to $1.762$ is *between* $0.025$ and $0.05,$ but you'd need software
to find the exact value. For example, using R you could see
that the P-value is $0.0467$ to four decimal places.
[In R 'pt` denotes the CDF of a t distribution.]

```
1 - pt(1.762, 20)
[1] 0.04667406
```

(2) ***Connections with R.*** Here are some additional bits of R output matching
earlier parts of this Answer. [In R, `qt` is an inverse CDF of a t distribution; `pnorm` is a normal CDF, and `qnorm` is a normal inverse CDF. (An inverse CDF is called a 'quantile' function.]

```
pnorm(1.96)
[1] 0.9750021
qnorm(.975)
[1] 1.959964
pt(1.725, 20)
[1] 0.9500259
qt(.95, 20)
[1] 1.724718
```

(3) Yours may be the last generation of students who will use books that have printed probability tables. [R is excellent statistical software available free of
charge for Windows, Mac, and UNIX operating systems from `www.r-project.org`. It does more than any one person
will ever need; if you try it, focus just on the parts *you* need.]